# Serialize array & put results into hidden text field?

Tags: php, serialization

I'm currently encountering a problem which is baffling me. There will be a lack of PHP mixed with HTML due to using a MVC Framework.

What i've got:

Form A on Page 1 with a submit button which directs user input from Form A to page 2 with a chunk of text for the user to read before continuing, a hidden text field which will contain a serialized array from Form A and a submit button to continue to the validation of user input.

My forms direct to the correct pages as required, the post array can be seralized providing I do not put it into a text field. The HTML from form A follows:

```
<form action="/RegisterInformation" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username, ex: JohnDoe ">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email, ex: JohnDoe@provider.com">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <textarea name="Referral" placeholder="Where Did You Hear About Us?"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-4 columns">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" class="button">
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

The redirect to page 2:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" large-12 columns">
            <p>
                <?php echo $data['PreregisterInformation']; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <form action="/Continue" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="SubmitInfo" value="<?php echo serialize($_POST); ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue"  class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the current example, i've got the text field set to being visible, so I can see what's going on.. But this is where it gets strange.

What i'm getting is two different types of results.

The first, is that when I echo the serialized array outside a input field. I get the desired results:

> a:6:{s:8:"Username";s:1:"s";s:8:"Password";s:1:"4";s:9:"cpassword";s:1:"4";s:5:"email";s:3:"asd";s:8:"Referral";s:3:"asd";s:6:"submit";s:8:"Continue";}

The second is when I use the following:

```
<input type="text" name="SubmitInfo" value="<?php echo serialize($_POST); ?>">
```

Which passes an invalid serialized array to page 3 breaking the whole process.

I assume it's not a HTML related error, but the new line break in the serialized array definition a:6. I have made an attempt to rectify this problem by removing the new line break with `str_replace`:

```
$Ser = serialize($_POST);
$Ser = nl2br($Ser);
$Ser = str_replace("<br>","00",$Ser);
echo $Ser;
```

which has proven not to work.

Comment: The problem is the double quotes `"` in the serialized data.  Use single quotes `'` to surround the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct solution of your problem, but have you tried `json_encode` or avoiding the hidden field by storing the date into `$_SESSION`?